# Searchkick: Elasticsearch not indexing "FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I've setup a new development environment on my iMac and moved my rails app from a macbook air. It was working fine and indexing the data as well. Using the same version of gems. When indexing it gives following error.

```
Searchkick::ImportError: {"type"=>"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=>"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"} on item with id '74'
```

Is there any way I can solve this issue by modifying my elasticsearch.yml?

Answer (score 5):

This solution from [salihsagdilekon](https://github.com/salihsagdilek) on [https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1040](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1040#issuecomment-354158085) resolved this same issue for me:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" > http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue today, and the following worked for me:

```rb
Model.search_index.clean_indices
```

Comment: Where did you put it?

Comment: `rails console`

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following in rails console:

```
MyModel.reindex
```